# Gradle is not allowing semantic versioning

Tags: gradle, versioning

I am trying to create a project with teh version as 0.1.1 but gradle build is failing

It is always forcing me to use 2 digit versions like 0.1 or 0.2

How to get rid of this?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/xypath/build.gradle' line: 14
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile build file '/xypath/build.gradle'.

  > startup failed:
  >   build file '/xypath/build.gradle': 14: unexpected token: 2 @ line 14, column 15.
  >    version = 0.1.2
  >                  ^

  1 error

My build.gradle looks like this

```
// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'

version = 0.1.2

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()    
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev157-1.19.1'
    compile "org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.7"
    compile 'org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:1.4.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.force.api:force-wsc:28.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    compile 'org.json:json:20131018'
    compile 'net.oauth.core:oauth:20090617'
    compile 'net.oauth.core:oauth-httpclient4:20090617'
    compile 'net.oauth.core:oauth-consumer:20090617'

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Gradle is just Groovy; `0.1.2` isn't a valid thing in Groovy.  Try `"0.1.2"` instead.

Comment: just a short explanation to this. 0.1 is interpreted as a digit in groovy and as Oliver pointed out you need to put 0.1.2 in quotes so it can be interpreted as a string in groovy

Answer (score -1):

After checking the available versions on gradle i can see that the oldest build version is 0.7, maybe you meant 1.2 not 0.1.2?